# Complex forms - Managing multiple models in a single form - (3rd degree madness)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, has-and-belongs-to-many

**I have isolated the problem in the second block of code below** (if you don't want all the details): I can create new users from the account model. I can't assign those users roles from the accounts model. I am using fields_for, this method does not work when I attempt to assign the role_ids to the roles model. My db is set up in the following way:

1. Account model has_many :**users**
2. User model has_and_belongs_to_many :**roles**,
   belongs_to :**accounts**
3. Roles model has_and_belongs_to_many :**users**

views/accounts/new.html.erb

```
<% for user in @account.users %>
 <% fields_for "account[user_attributes][]", user do |account_fields| %>
      <p>Login  : <%= account_fields.text_field :login %>
      <p>Email  : <%= account_fields.text_field :email %>
      <p>Password  : <%= account_fields.password_field :password %>
      <p>Confirm Password  : <%= account_fields.password_field :password_confirmation %>
      <%= account_fields.hidden_field :account_id, :value => :id %>

    <% end %>
<% end %>

<% for role in @account.users.first.roles %>
<% fields_for "account[role_attributes]]", role do |role_fields| %>
  <%= role_fields.hidden_field :role_ids, :value => '[1]' %>
 <% end %>
<% end%>
```

Associated setter methods in the account.rb model: using the stacktrace I have isolated the problem to "undefined method `roles' for #" on line 34, marked below:

```
def user_attributes=(user_attributes)
   user_attributes.each do |attributes|
   users.build(attributes)
   end
end

def role_attributes=(role_attributes)
    role_attributes.each do |attributes|
    users.roles.build(attributes)   #error here (stacktrace)
  end
end
```

finally, within the accounts controller I build the users and roles in memory:

```
 def new
    @account = Account.new
    1.times { @account.users.build }
    1.times { @account.users.first.roles.build }
```

The @accounts.users.first.roles.build proof from consol:

```
>> account
=> #<Account id: 1, subdomain: "justinzollars", created_at: "2010-02-08 14:41:13", updated_at: "2010-02-08 14:41:13">
>> account.users
=> [#<User id: 13, login: "jayz", email: "jz@jz.com", crypted_password: "f9a3d618fc650d285a90f9775508c13784891b97", salt: "f497a7dd909b695caff1f6310e710245615d55b6", created_at: "2010-02-08 20:25:48", updated_at: "2010-02-08 20:25:48", remember_token: nil, remember_token_expires_at: nil, account_id: 1>, #<User id: 16, login: "jasonwade23", email: "jasonwade@gmail.com", crypted_password: "06581b47cfac7a529773d61dc0b1d5d6c0da6c08", salt: "93f8b99cd9da60b904d553fcc7843bfb66352c3e", created_at: "2010-02-13 07:46:14", updated_at: "2010-02-13 07:46:14", remember_token: nil, remember_token_expires_at: nil, account_id: 1>]
>> account.users.first
=> #<User id: 13, login: "jayz", email: "jz@jz.com", crypted_password: "f9a3d618fc650d285a90f9775508c13784891b97", salt: "f497a7dd909b695caff1f6310e710245615d55b6", created_at: "2010-02-08 20:25:48", updated_at: "2010-02-08 20:25:48", remember_token: nil, remember_token_expires_at: nil, account_id: 1>
>> account.users.first.roles
=> [#<Role id: 1, name: "admin">, #<Role id: 2, name: "alt">]
>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, so in models:

```
# Account model
accepts_nested_attributes_for :users

# User model
accepts_nested_attributes_for :roles
```

Then you should remove `user_attributes=` and `role_attributes=` methods.
Your form should look like this:

```
<% form_for @account do |f| %>
   <% fields_for :users do |u| %>
      ... # user fields
      <% fields_for :roles do |r| %>
         ... # role fields
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit 'Save' %>
<% end %>
```

It will automaticaly iterate over all users associated with account and all roles associated with user.

For more details read [here](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes).

EDIT:
You can assign roles to user, in controller:

```
role = Roles.find(some_id)
@user.roles << role
```

or

```
@user.role_ids = [2, 4, 6]
```

However I'm not sure how to add roles with `has_and_belongs_to_many` association. You are using `@user.roles.build` method which will create new role and associate it with user. If you want to add a role you should do it with one of two examples above. But how to create a from for it? I don't know. I would add a model for `users_roles` table and add to user model:

```
has_many :users_roles
accepts_nested_attributes_for :users_roles # you should add here also some :reject_if
```

Then insted of `fields_for :roles` I would add in form:

```
<% fields_for :users_roles do |ur| %>
  <%= ur.select :role_id, Role.all.collect {|r| [r.name, r.id] }, {:include_blank => true} %>
<% end %>
```

Then in your controller you should add something like `3.times { @user.users_roles.build }`. If you want to have nice "Add" and "Remove" links that create for you new role with javascript, take a look [here](http://github.com/alloy/complex-form-examples/tree/) - it is really nice example how to handle it.

Comment: I can set new roles, I need to be able to assign current roles. An SQL equivalent of:  

SQL (0.1ms)   INSERT INTO "roles_users" ("role_id", "user_id") VALUES (6, 29)

are there provisions for this in creating a new model?

Comment: where of coure the role_id would be fixed, and the user_id would be the current new user_id

Comment: I added some explanation in my answer. Hope you'll find it useful!